# Do I have to use "def application" with the wsgi_module?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

So I installed python on my server and I'm using the wsgi_module with apache.

Do all my python programs have to use this format:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    headers = []
    headers.append(('Content-Type', 'text/plain'))
    write = start_response('200 OK', headers)

    input = environ['wsgi.input']
    output = cStringIO.StringIO()

    print >> output, "test"

    output.write(input.read(int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', '0'))))
    return [output.getvalue()]
```

Is there anyway to set it up so I can write python scripts and just have:

```
print "test"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your script certainly need to have **callable** (not necessarily a function, it can also be a class with __call__ method defined) that accepts *environ* and *start_response* arguments as it is a part of [wsgi standard](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) and that is the way how it works.

The way you'd like to write scripts in PHP-style like "print something" doesn't work. There's a currently dead initiative called initially [PSP](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-psp.html) (Python Server Pages) that mixed up code and templates, but it couldn't gain popularity as it's certainly not a Python-way of writing applications.

Comment: alright I guess more importantly I want to be able to print out things sort of like the php flush method. Like I'd like to be able to print, sleep(1), print. Is that sort of thing possible under these wsgi standards?

Comment: @Rawr The things you are talking about are nicely documented in WSGI standard here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#buffering-and-streaming. Just spend some time to watch it up, and all questions should get answered.